# html table to convert list or stack datastrure without javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, html

i am developer for android web App.

i using javascript interface on Android Webview.

so that, i have some problem.

how to convert html table with only javascript?

```
<table>
<tr> 
<td> <input type=button value='test'> </input>
</td>
<td> <form> <h1> test heading </h1> </form>
</td>
<tr>
<h1> heading 2 </h1>
</tr>
<tr>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td> td1 </td>
<td> td2 </td>
<td> td3 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</tr>
```

and Javascript Code

```
var table_index = 0;

function node_init() {
    var nodes = document.body.children;

    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        var node = nodes[i];

        if (node.tagName == 'TABLE') {
            node_init_table_name(node, ++table_index);
        } 
    }
}

function node_init_table_name(table, index) {
    table.setAttribute('node_tableName', 'table ' + index);

    var cellIndex = 0;

    for (var row = 0; row < table.rows.length; row++) {
        for (var column = 0; column < table.rows[row].cells.length; column++) {
            var cell = table.rows[row].cells[column];

            cell.setAttribute('cellName', cellIndex++);
            if (cell.childElementCount > 0) {
                var nodes = cell.children;
                var inner_table_index = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                    var node = nodes[i];

                    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                        han_initChildNodes(node);

                        var pNode = node.parentNode;
                        if (pNode) {
                            var hasChild = node.getAttribute('child');
                            var focusChild = node.getAttribute('current_child');
                            pNode.setAttribute('child', hasChild);
                            pNode.setAttribute('current_child', focusChild);
                        }
                    }

                    if (node.tagName == 'TABLE') {++inner_table_index;
                        var inner_index = index + "-" + inner_table_index;
                        han_init_table_name(node, inner_index);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }/* end for*/

    table.setAttribute('cellCount', cellIndex);
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what it is your problem please?

Comment: i use language on javascript for parsing html table.